# How can I pass a matrix vector into a function argument in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, evolutionary-algorithm

I have a 10 x 3 Matrix and would like to use each of the 10 rows as arguments to a function expecting 3 arguments using an iteration from 1 to 10.
Problem is that I cannot pass each row vector directly into the function expecting 3 arguments. How can I convert the matrix rows to a format acceptable by my function?

Here is the function:

```
XXX = obj(Kc, T1, T2);
```

Calling code:

```
for i = 1:100                               
    pop(i,1) = 50 - rand*(50-1);
    pop(i,2) = 1 - rand*(1-0.1);
    pop(i,3) = 0.2 - rand*(0.2-0.01); 
    Kc(i) = pop(i,1); 
    T1(i) = pop(i,2); 
    T2(i) = pop(i,3); 

end

for j = 1:10
    kk = randperm(100);
    Tour1 = pop(kk(1:10),:);
    ZET(j) = obj(Tour1(j,:));

end
```

Tour1 is the 10 x 3 matrix whose rows need to become Kc, T1, T2.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not `Zet(j) = obj(Tour1(j,1),Tour1(j,2),Tour1(j,3));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to a cell array:

```
for j = 1:10
    kk = randperm(100);
    Tour1 = pop(kk(1:10),:);
    temp = mat2cell(Tour1(j,:),1,ones(1,numel(Tour1(j,:))))
    ZET(j) = obj(temp{:});
end
```

Comment: Thanks guys, you are far too kind.