# Using a vector as an input for a function of multiple inputs in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, variables

I want to use a vector input such of dimension [m;1] in a function that takes in m number of inputs. For example:

```
syms x1 x2;

f = x1^2 + x2^2;
F = matlabFunction(f);
x = [1;1];
F(x);
```

The above code does not work because F is a function of 2 inputs and it only sees the vector x as a single input. I know I can say F(x(1),x(2)) and the above would work but I want it to work for a function of m variables and a vector of m length.

All help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a matrix vector into a function argument in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188884/how-can-i-pass-a-matrix-vector-into-a-function-argument-in-matlab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to first convert `x` to a cell and then pass it with `{:}`.

```
xcell = num2cell(x);
F(xcell{:});
```

Alternately, you can specify that you want `x1` and `x2` to be passed as an array when you call `matlabFunction` using the [`Vars` parameter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html#input_argument_namevalue_vars).

```
F = matlabFunction(f, 'Vars', {[x1, x2]});
F([1 1]);
```

Comment: The top one worked beautifully. Thanks for the help and the quick response.

Comment: @ktobrien if this worked for you please consider marking it as a solution to help anyone with a similar question